# Checking if CKEDITOR is defined or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ckeditor

I use one function to call an ajax script from two different pages. 
The first and original page had CKEDITOR library defined and included and it work perfectly however, page 2 is like a mini version of page one and there is no ckeditor support here so i wanted a simple way of cheking if ckeditor is defined or not so i know the appropriate way to get the form data to post to my ajax script

this is my code sample but its not working...what am i missing?...am more of a php guy not js

`if(CKEDITOR !== undefined) { var msg = CKEDITOR.instances['msg'].getData();} else{var msg = $("#msg").val()};`

if its any good i use jquery on both pages.
The `if(CKEDITOR !== undefined) { var msg = CKEDITOR.instances['msg'].getData();}` part works fine, the else park does not work

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps it would be better to write `if( typeof(CKEDITOR) !== "undefined" )...`.

Comment: typeof is not a method call, no need for the ( and ). `if( typeof CKEDITOR !== "undefined" )`

Comment: @epascarello `typeof` is an operator and does not require the parentheses, I like adding them for clarity - even though you and jslint complain :)

Answer (score 0):

if (CKEDITOR !== undefined) {
... rest of code
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).